# Set Delegate as Existing View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm setting a delegate on a segue, but I need it to be set to the existing `SfnViewController` rather than what appears to be happening here which is creating a new one.

How can I access the existing `SfnViewController` to pass it through?

```
class ViewerListController {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        editViewer = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Viewer
        performSegueWithIdentifier("editViewer", sender: indexPath)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "editViewer" {
            let editViewerViewController = segue.destinationViewController.topViewController as! EditViewerViewController
            editViewerViewController.viewer = editViewer

            //Need this as the existing SfnViewController
            editViewerViewController.delegate = SfnViewController()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't really help you because you haven't provided enough information. You say you have an existing SfnViewController.

- When and where was this object created?
- Who owns it?
- Does your ViewListController have a reference to it?

If your only have one shared SfnViewController for you entire object you should consider following the singleton design pattern and making your SfnViewController a singleton. Then you'd use a class method of the SfnViewController class to get a reference to the singleton.

Comment: Thanks.. this kinda kicked my brain into action and I managed to access it with an existing delegate.

Comment: So can you edit your question to better explain the situation, then post an answer to your own question explaining how you solved it? This is a site for learning, after all.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using some specific controller which you can determine in the tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: method, then you should send it in the "sender" property when calling performSegueWithIdentifier like this:

```
class ViewerListController {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        editViewer = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Viewer
        performSegueWithIdentifier("editViewer", sender: editViewer)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "editViewer" {
            let editViewerViewController = segue.destinationViewController.topViewController as! EditViewerViewController
            editViewerViewController.viewer = editViewer

            let editViewer = sender as! EditViewerViewController
            editViewerViewController.delegate = editViewer.delegate
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: editViewer is an Object rather than a view controller. ViewerListController is a sidebar, SfnViewController is the view that slides away when the sidebar opens. I somehow need to access the existing SfnViewController from ViewerListController but I'm not entirely sure how..